# Reinsert special character * into strings at predefined positions

Tags: r, string, dplyr, sapply

(This question is based on a previous question [Convert letters with duplicates to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73011685/convert-letters-with-duplicates-to-numbers))

I have series of events and non-events in column `aoi`, with events expressed as capital letters and non-events expressed as "*":

```
df <- data.frame(
  Partcpt = c("B","A","B","C","A","B"),
  aoi = c("B*B*B","*A*C*A*C","*B*B","A*C","*A*","*")
)
```

I need to convert the letters to consecutive numbers unless they are duplicates, in which case the previous number should be repeated. This conversion is accomplished by this:

```
df$aoi_0 <- sapply(strsplit(df$aoi, split = ""), function(x) paste(match(x[x!="*"], unique(x[x!="*"])), collapse = ""))

df
  Partcpt      aoi aoi_0
1       B    B*B*B   111
2       A *A*C*A*C  1212
3       B     *B*B    11
4       C      A*C    12
5       A      *A*     1
6       B        *
```

But now the information on the non-events is lost. How can I reinstate that information in the strings themselves, by re-inserting the "*" character where appropriate, like so:

```
df
  Partcpt      aoi      aoi_0
1       B    B*B*B      1*1*1
2       A *A*C*A*C   *1*2*1*2
3       B     *B*B       *1*1
4       C      A*C        1*2
5       A      *A*        *1*
6       B        *          *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the anonymous function with an `ifelse()` to return `*` if the input is `*` but otherwise to follow the logic of your previous code,  i.e. match the input to the vector of unique values.

```r
df$aoi_1  <- sapply(
  strsplit(df$aoi, split = ""), 
  \(x) paste0(
    ifelse(
      x=="*", 
      "*", 
      match(x, unique(x[x!="*"]))
    ), collapse = ""
  )
)

df
#   Partcpt      aoi aoi_0    aoi_1
# 1       B    B*B*B   111    1*1*1
# 2       A *A*C*A*C  1212 *1*2*1*2
# 3       B     *B*B    11     *1*1
# 4       C      A*C    12      1*2
# 5       A      *A*     1      *1*
# 6       B        *              *
```

Comment: Or grab the indices of `x != "*"` and use `replace`; `sapply(strsplit(dt$aoi, split = ""), \(x) {i = x!= "*"; paste(replace(x, i, match(x[i], unique(x[i]))), collapse = "")})`. Faster on larger data (if speed ever would be an issue). Cheers

Comment: @Henrik I like this - I was thinking there is probably a way to do it a lot faster. I think this is probably a significant improvement. I have a feeling `Hmisc::translate()` may be even faster than `replace()` but I haven't run any benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which is based on the following ideas:

1. Try to match `*` with `unique(x[x!="*"]`.
2. This outcomes *no match* for `*`.
3. Configure `nomatch = 0`.
4. Use `gsub` to replace `0` by `*`.

```r
df$aoi_0 <- sapply(strsplit(df$aoi, split = ""), 
  function(x) gsub("0", "*", paste(match(x, unique(x[x!="*"]), nomatch = 0),
    collapse = "")))

df

#>   Partcpt      aoi    aoi_0
#> 1       B    B*B*B    1*1*1
#> 2       A *A*C*A*C *1*2*1*2
#> 3       B     *B*B     *1*1
#> 4       C      A*C      1*2
#> 5       A      *A*      *1*
#> 6       B        *        *
```

Comment: Nice and clever!